# grep: detect multi-line pattern with double capture

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have file, say test.s that contains several trivial infinite loops:

```
.LBB7_7:
        branch .LBB7_7
```

Labels may be totally different, but all are like .LBB\d_\d+

I want some neat way to process such things with grep or sed one-liner.

Now I am doing this way. First I calculate all labels:

```
grep -oP 'branch .\KLBB\d_\d+' minimize.s
```

And then in bash for loop I looking up label with one line below with `grep -A1 "^.$i:"` and checking its output for `branch $i`

Can I do better (without explicit bash processing with grep only)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```bsh
$ cat ip.txt
foo
baz
.LBB7_7:
        branch .LBB7_7
xyzyadsf
.LBB8_3:
    mov a, b
        branch .LBB8_3
nop

$ grep -zoP '(\.LBB\d_\d+):\s*branch\h+\1\n' ip.txt
.LBB7_7:
        branch .LBB7_7
```

- `-z` will use ASCII NUL as record separator instead of default newline character. Assuming your input doesn't have NUL characters, this will cause whole file to be slurped
- `(\.LBB\d_\d+)` capture label, but can't specify to match at start of line
- `:\s*branch\h+\1\n` condition to check for infinite loop